# NameError when calling method from different module in Python

Tags: python, function, import, python-import

I have two modules in Python 3—main.py and gui.py—which are both in the same directory. My code is listed here:

main.py:

```
import gui

if __name__ == "__main__":
    interface = gui.Gui()
    interface.func1()

def foo():
    interface.func2()
```

gui.py:

```
import main

class Gui:
    def func1(self):
        main.foo()
    def func2(self):
        pass
```

When calling `main.foo()` from gui.py, I get the following exception:

```
NameError: name 'interface' is not defined
```

If I move the `foo()` declaration to the top of the main.py file and then call it from main.py, I do not get this exception.

Why does this error occur when calling `main.foo()` from gui.py?

Note: This is my first question on StackOverflow, so I'm sorry if it is not well-written. Please tell me how I could improve it.

Comment: The whole point of `if __name__ == '__main__':` is that it's only true when you're running the file as a script, not when you're `import`ing it. So, when you do `import main`, that code doesn't run, so `interface` never gets created, so you can't use it. If you want it to be created even on an `import main`, just don't put that code inside an `if __name__ == '__main__':` check.

Comment: But that may not immediately fix your problem, because you also have a circular import. Whichever module you try to `import` will immediately `import` the other one. One of them has to finish first. If `gui` finishes first, that's fine; nobody is calling that code that uses `main.foo` until after the import is done. But if `main` finishes first, it has top-level code that tries to do `interface .= gui.Foo()`, when `Foo` doesn't exist yet. The solution to _this_ problem is a little trickier, but the short version is: break up the circle.

Comment: @abarnert I am still confused as to why my code does not work, though. I am running `main.py` first, so `__name__ == "__main__"` and `interface` _is_ created. Why, then, does `foo()` not know that `interface` has been defined? Could you please clarify?

Comment: OK, you have a whole other problem on top of the circular imports: You should never use the same file as your main script and also a module, for exactly this reason. Whatever file is being run as a script is named `__main__`. But when you `import main`, you're running the same source as a module named `main`. Often you'll get away with this, but put it together with a circular import, and you end up `__main__` constructing a `gui.Gui()` and calling `func1`, which calls `main.foo`, not `__main__.foo`—they have different module globals, and there is no `interface` in the former's.

Comment: If that isn't clear, I can search for a dup or write a more detailed answer; let me know. (But meanwhile, it may help to step through your imports in a debugger and look at `__name__`, `id(sys.modules[__name__])`, etc. at multiple places—or just add a mess of `print`s to get the same info.)